# git: automated builds with pull and merges?

Tags: git, automated-builds

Hi is there some software i can use which automatically pulls from known repositories and does full build? then repeats on the next known repository for that project OR reverts the pull if there is a merge or build error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use **[Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/)** (freeware) with:

- [Hudson Git Plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Git+Plugin) (obviously)
- one Hudson job per repo and per project to pull and build
- [Hudson Join Plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Join+Plugin) to only trigger the next job if the previous has succeeded.